# Round Progress Bar around drawable View

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

Is there any library or custom view like HTC Music App's PlayPauseButton ?It is a drawable surrounded in a circular progress bar which shows the song's progress. So any suggestion on a library or how to? Thank you for any help.

Example: http://www73.zippyshare.com/v/6ElodH7W/file.html

Comment: maybe this can point you in the right direction?
https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this myself, but maybe this library can be of use to you?
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1446

It provides you with a round progress bar, of which you can adjust the circle size and post progress to it.

If you use this and put an imageButton of a play button underneath it, this might do the trick.